# Byname or patronymic names for daughters?

Tags: old-english

Bynames in various texts and genealogies include the suffix *-ing* to indicate the son of. Example would be Cynric son of Cerdic written as Cynric Cerdic*ing*.

Was there a similar practice for daughter's "bynames?"

Comment: I'm not aware of this use of _-ing_ in English. Is it archaic?

Comment: The list of Wessex kings is an example: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monarchs_of_Wessex)

Comment: Since those are all from the 6th to the 10th century, I guess that answers my question about it being archaic.

Comment: I know Old Norse had this -dottir suffix for women. So Sveinn's daughter Helga would be called "Helga Sveinnsdottir". Not sure if English people ever had this system before.

Comment: Iceland still uses the -dottir suffix.

Answer (score 1):

For Old English, there's no evidence that there was a suffix for daughters corresponding to -ing. At least I'm not aware of one, and there's no mention in [Okasha's 2011 book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3z0-fUT70DsC) on women's names in Old English, or in [Colman's 2014 book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ve_8AwAAQBAJ) on the grammar of names in Anglo-Saxon England.

Colman actually suggests (2014: 140–141) that even *-ing* was no longer used as a patronymic during the late Old English period, though it started out that way.